# raco: docs failure query-exec: unable to open the database file

Tags: racket, upgrade

After a system update (Arch Linux), some package was not found anymore (megaparsack). I installed it with `raco pkg install megaparsack` but got this message during installation:

```
raco setup: docs failure: query-exec: unable to open the database file
  error code: 14
  SQL: "ATTACH $1 AS other"
  database: #<path:/home/ploppz/.racket/6.12/doc/docindex.sqlite>
  mode: 'read-only
  file permissions: (write read)
```

Why? Should I have used sudo?
Despite this failure, code that uses megaparsack now runs fine.

Comment: This looks like a permissions error with the database. Could you show us the permissions you have set for this directory? Also you could try deleting and rebuilding the database.

Comment: @LeifAndersen `doc/`: `drwxr-xr-x`, `doc/docindex.sqlite`: `-rw-r--r--`. All owned by my user. How do I rebuild the database?

Comment: If memory serves, you can just delete the file and run `raco setup`. If you're worried you can back up the file somewhere else before you delete it.

Comment: @LeifAndersen `raco setup` fails: https://bpaste.net/show/7cf008961788 (that is immediately after `raco setup: --- creating launchers --- \n
raco setup: launcher: <console-bin>/raco`

Comment: It looks (quick look) as though you installed as root, so your launchers are now owned by root and can't be deleted by raco setup. Apologies if I'm misreading your paste.

Comment: I also run into this - Using racket 6.12 on Gentoo (`dev-scheme/racket-6.12-r1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by `docindex.sqlite` missing from your system-scope documentation directory. You can check what directory this is via: `(require setup/dirs) (find-user-doc-dir)`. On Archlinux this is `/usr/share/doc/racket/`. If it's missing, chances are you need to install another package. **edit: Archlinux fixed this in [`7.1-1`](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/racket&id=74f3ef520815451d01604527b2080319edee4616) - see [this](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60413) Archlinux bug report.**

Without the aforementioned file, `raco pkg install <pkgname>` will not be able to finalize the installation of documentation to your user-scope, but the packages should be usable otherwise.

I encountered this issue in a slightly different manner - on Gentoo `/usr/share/doc` is compressed by default, and the `dev-scheme/racket` package was installed with a `docindex.sqlite.bz2` while the code still looks for the original path (and sqlite3 probably cannot read bzip2 files). **edit: I got this fixed in official portage.**

Comment: Hey Winny, you said you got this fixed in official portage, but I'm still getting this error on the very latest dev-scheme/racket-7.2 (as well as with older 7.1).

Comment: Hi @AndrewKravchuk it appears when using the `-doc` USE flag, the `docindex.sqlite` is still compressed (and not as its expected path). The work around is to enable the `doc` USE flag for `dev-scheme/racket`. You probably want this anyway, to install local documentation. I recommend reporting this to the gentoo bug tracker in the meantime.

Comment: For Ubuntu systems, install `racket-doc` package may solve this problem.